# Having an issue with using Bash in Vim on an Ubuntu system. "/bin/bash: cso: command not found, shell returned 127"

Tags: bash, vim

I have coursework to do which revolves around using a bash script to perform various actions. I've been attempting to use Vim as it was recommended to me, however having some issues using it. This is the what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Insert command, option, source-file and target-directory"
read com opt sf td
echo "Hello $com $opt $sf $td"
```

The final echo line is just to test whether the rest works. When I run the script, I get the following error.

"/bin/bash: cso: command not found

shell returned 127"

[Image of error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Urem.png)

I am fairly new to both bash and vim so I apologise if this is a silly question or an easy fix. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your output for `!echo $PATH`

Comment: @chrisz They are using an absolute path, so `$PATH` is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah good point. Wasn't thinking

Comment: @serae What do you get if you `echo $SHELL` on the terminal? and `ls /bin/bash`?

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: @123 echo $SHELL gives me "/bin/bash" and also gives me "/bin/bash"

Comment: @BenjaminW. I've been doing it by using :!%

Comment: `:!%` is a history expansion command for "the word matched by the most recent `?string?` search", so it could be anything. If your script's name is `script`, you should be able to make it executable (`chmod +x script`), then just run it with `./script`.

Comment: to follow up on Benjamin, your script name is "cso", and the shell cannot find an executable file with that name in your $PATH. Use `:!bash %` in vmi to run it

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you so much, this has fixed my problem and now my script runs! Thank you, it is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you so much, this has fixed my problem and now my script runs! Thank you, it is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @glennjackman: The script already has `#!/bin/bash` at the top. There's no need to specify *again* that `bash` should be used to execute it. Type `./cso` -- or, given the way the OP is invoking it, `:!./%`. This will work for any kind of script, for example if you're editing a Perl or Python script.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, assuming the script is executable

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes -- but if it isn't, there's no point in the `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
/bin/bash: cso: command not found
```

means that the bash shell could not find a command named `cso` in your `$PATH`.

What you didn't mention in your question is that the script you're trying to run is named `cso`. (You also misquoted the error message in your question title; I've fixed that.)

The current directory, `.`, is not normally in your `$PATH` -- and for good reason. (Having `.` in `$PATH` creates security problems. Those problems aren't quite as bad if it's at the end of `$PATH`, but it's still a bad idea.)

To run a script in the current directory, precede its name with `./`, an explicit relative path for the current directory. So type `./cso` rather than `cso`.

In comments, you say that you invoke it by typing `:!%` in vim (something else that should have been in the question). `:!` executes an external command, and `%` refers to the current file, so you're executing the script that you're currently executing. Type `:!./%` instead. It will expand to `:!./cso`.